# What is the opposite phrase of "ALL CAPS"?

Tags: phrases, antonyms

As far as I know, we say that the words in which every letter is in upper-case as "ALL CAPS".

Then how can we say for *not* "ALL CAPS"?

Something like "Not all caps".

Comment: Yes, but it is used by editors and people like that. You certainly will not find it in actual writing. The opposite is: all LC, in editor's jargon. LC=lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would usually say something like:

> All lower case.

There isn't a direct opposite, most likely because "CAPSLOCK" is a thing, and its opposite would just be the absence of that thing, as opposed to another thing.

**Update**

You may also mean "proper case", which is where the first letter of each word is capitalised, e.g.,:

> This Is Proper Case

For something like "Not all caps", you may be looking for "sentence case".

> This is sentence case.

Comment: No, I don't think so. All lower case means 'all lower case', dosn't it?

Comment: Isn't that the opposite of ALL CAPS?

Comment: Mmm.. Sorry, I mean I want to know about words like 'Some word'.

Comment: I updated my answer. I would advise looking into the proper definition for each case, and perhaps doing a bit more reading on grammatical cases in general, to make sure you have the right one.

Comment: The opposite of all caps is all lower case. No doubt about it. And there is no reason to write all caps as ALL CAPS, unless there is a specific reason. all caps is an editorial expression.

Answer (score 0):

There is so-called "s[entence case](https://www.thoughtco.com/sentence-case-titles-1691944)" (where only proper nouns and the first letter of the sentence is capitalised.

There Is Title Case in which All Words Except Particles Are Capitalised

and then there is lowercase in which no words are capitalised.

andThereIsCamelCaseWhichIsUsedBySomeProgrammingLanguges. dontUseItForWriting!

We rarely use the expression "sentence case" because this is the default.  All writing should be in sentence case (except when there is a specific reason otherwise)